# Zend ViewScript Decorator the big picture, overall use.how to?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

It's true I've seen a lot of examples on stackoverflow and many from Google search but apparently nobody showed the big picture of how things falls under one another, even from the manual itself.

I've just picked Zend Framework(1.10.8) and when creating forms I've finally found that the ViewScript for now is much easier for me to configure but wasn't the case.

I have a`module booking`, with `UserController`  and `createAction` in it.Under `/application/modules/booking/views/scripts/user` I have `create.phtml` and `custormerForm.phtml`.

From my understanding, at the end of everything my form with it's rendering will be shown in my `create.phtml` as in my form will use the `customerForm.phtml` for it's visual and injected in the create view.

So I went ahead and created a simple form

```
function init(){
  $this->setMethod("post");

  $name = New Zend_Form_Element_Text("name");
  $name->setLabel("Name: ")
  ->setOptions(array("size"=>"35"))
  ->setRequired(true)
  ->addValidator("NotEmpty", true);

  $surname = New Zend_Form_Element_Text("surname");
  $surname->setLabel("Surname: ")
  ->setOptions(array("size"=>"35"))
  ->setRequired(true)
  ->addValidator("Alpha", true);

  $this->addElement($name)
  ->addElement($surname)
  ->addElement($submit);
}
```

Now here is the createAction in UserController

```
public function createAction(){
  $this->view->show = "Please Enter your Details";

  $form = new Hotel_Form_Entity();
  $form->setAction("/booking/user/create");
                //and here set the for to be displayed at described in customerForm view
  $form->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript',array('viewScript'=>'customerForm.phtml'))));
                //so here i set the form to form variable accessible in create view
  $this->view->form = $form;
  if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
    if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
      $values = $form->getValues();
      $this->_helper->flashMessenger("Thank you.Form processed");

      $this->_forward("success","user","booking",$values);
    }
  }
}
```

Now these are the create.phtml and customerForm.phtml

```
<!-- create.phtml -->
<h4><?php echo $this->show; ?></h4><br/><!--  -->
<p><?php echo $this->form; ?></p><br/> 

 <!-- customerForm.phtml --> 
<div style="padding: 10 0 0 15; border: solid 1.5px #999">
 <form action="<?php echo $this->element->getAction(); ?>" method="<?php echo $this->element->getMethod(); ?>">
  <table>
     <tr>
       <td><?php echo $this->element->name; ?></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><?php echo $this->element->surname; ?></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="2"><?php echo $this->element->submit; ?> </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
  </form> 
 </div>
```

so when I hit my page as in http://localhost/project/booking/user/create
it just displays the layout with the content of the create view with no form. Nothing in page source, no errors.

Did I get the wrong idea on how to use this or I'm just doing something wrong in the code?And since i'm using Zend framework 1.10.8 there seems not to be any tutorial covering the whole thing on ViewScript decorator.

Can anyone please give me a hand and share his valuable experience here? Thank you very much for reading this. Maybe I'll make this a tutorial who  knows :D

Comment: first tip about decorator when you learning decorator is use
$this->form->clearDecorators(); to start with no  decorator  and to see how your forms resulting

Comment: i've done that and always check the source of the page.I just need to get a simple viewscript decorator working to start personalization and fully get the overall understanding.unfortunately i don't have too much time to really play with it.Thanks for your tip though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i've figured it out.Everything in coding side was correct.
i just had to put the customerForm.phtml into `/modules/booking/views/scripts/` and that's it.thanks for those who tried to help me.I can now learn how to customize the standard decorators as Tawfekov tried to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'd like to rewrite your action and lets forget about customerForm.phtml for a while

```
public function createAction(){
  $this->view->show = "Please Enter your Details";

  $form = new Hotel_Form_Entity();
  $form->setAction("/booking/user/create");
  $form->setElementDecorators(array('viewHelper', 'formElements')));
  $this->view->form = $form;
  if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
    if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
      $values = $form->getValues();
      $this->_helper->flashMessenger("Thank you.Form processed");

      $this->_forward("success","user","booking",$values);
    }}}
```

what formElements decorators do

> Zend_Form_Decorator_FormElements
>   Forms, display groups, and sub forms
>   are collections of elements. In order
>   to render these elements, they utilize
>   the FormElements decorator, which
>   iterates through all items, calling
>   render() on each and joining them with
>   the registered separator. It can
>   either append or prepend content
>   passed to it.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html

I hope i did it right , FYI i haven't test the action yet :)

Comment: thanks for the effort to explain how i could use the standard decorators.i will look at it but really what i need now is to understand if i'm on the right path with viewscript which looks much much simpler to me.Can you please look at and tell me what i'm doing wrong.i just need something to get going. thank you ;)